# Insert documents into collection unless they are already inserted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I get a list of objects from an API:

```
let sold = [
 {  objId: 3240747,
    soldDate: '2018-09-27',
    soldPrice: 4610000,
    apartmentNumber: '1202',
    soldPriceSource: 'bid',
  },
  { objId: 3234263,
    soldDate: '2018-09-24',
    soldPrice: 2580000,
    soldPriceSource: 'bid',
  }
...
]
```

I store these in a collection:

```
soldCollection.insertMany(sold)
```

Some of the objects have been retrieved before, and I only want to store the once that are not already in the database.

```
 dbo.collection("sold").createIndex({ "objId": 1 }, { unique: true })
```

What would be an efficient way of doing this? Should I ask for each object before storing it or is there method for dealing with this?

Comment: You can just insert into the database since you are adding a `unique` key. Mongodb will not insert if it already exists. Check for errors if you want to do something extra if it already exists, otherwise just ignore the error.

Comment: And if memory serves me correctly there is an option in `insertMany` on how to handle errors as in stop or ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `insertMany` will stop inserting when first error occurs (`E11000 duplicate key error` in this case). You can change that behavior by specifying `ordered` parameter set to `false`. In that case you'll get a list of errors from failed inserts however all valid documents will be inserted succesfully:

```
db.sold.insertMany(sold, { ordered: false })
```

docs example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html#unordered-inserts)

Comment: cool, I hadn't even noticed it worked at all. Is there some way of disabling this specific error? Either for this operation of in general.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` in MongoDB however with unordered I think this can be considered more like a warning than error, it only informs you that some inserts failed however entire "batch" is processed succesfully